# Voting mechanism with IP validation and allowing only one by user: problem in getting user IP address with two app servers and apache in front

Tags: java, apache, coldfusion

We have a voting mechanism that we want to restrict to only allow one vote by user.

We've tried to validate by IP address, but the problem is that when we get the user's IP address in the applicational server it shows always the apache IP address (we have two applicational servers with apache in front of them).

We are using ColdFusion variable CGI.REMOTE_ADDR to get the user IP.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

We would like to avoid the use of sessions or cookies.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to use the [X-Forward-For header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) header
instead of the source ip, assuming your apache instances are putting it into the request.

Comment: You're right! In the meanwhile i've found this post http://jeremiahx.com/2008/03/02/howto-reading-the-x-forwarded-for-header-in-coldfusion/ for coldfusion. Thks a lot!

Comment: The safest way to access X-Forwarded-For in Adobe Coldfusion is `getPageContext().getRequest().getHeader("X-Forwarded-For")`